# Jquery datepicker not popping up

Tags: jquery, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

Ok I already succeeded doing this on my other project.
Unfortunately it doesn't work on the project im currently doing can someone pls give an insights on whats wrong about my code tnx!

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="NonOperatingDays.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
     .ui-datepicker 
          {
            background: #FFFFFF;
            border: 1px solid #888888;
            color: #888888;
          }
          </style>
      <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" language ="javascript">
        function pageLoad() {
            $(function () {
                $(".datepicker").datepicker({ dateformat: "YYYY-MM-DD" });
            });
        }  </script>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" CssClass="datepicker"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check your console are you getting any error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually to complete @Wilson Huang answer rather than using pageload you have to use jquery ready otherwise jquery widgets wont work

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
     $(".datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" });
    });
```

Also make sure **dateFormat** is camel cased and don't forget to add the css and javascript links

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: :( i tried replacing my code with your code. and placing your scripts in the head tag still doesn't work:( i dont know whats the reason behind this

Comment: see this is the jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/kia3d/NpU34/ and it is perfectly working

Answer (score 0):

have a look: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

You don't need "function pageLoad()".

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({ dateformat: "yy-mm-dd" });
  });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is working code :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-MM-dd' });
    });
</script>
```

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" CssClass="datepicker"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
</form>
```